# How to figure out that the data has been loaded is some rows when using Ext.data.operation and ajaxProxy?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4

the code is here:

```
Ext.define('Book', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'title', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'pages', type: 'int'}, 
        {name: 'numChapters', type: 'int'}
    ]           
});

var ajaxProxy = Ext.create('Ext.data.proxy.Ajax', {
    url: 'books.json',
    model: 'Book'
});

var operation = Ext.create('Ext.data.Operation', {
    action: 'read',
    start: 0,
    limit: 5
});

operation.read();
```

books.json contains 6 rows, when i try the code bellow, i get 6 rows, when i expected its load 5 rows.

```
ajaxProxy.read(operation, function ()
{
    console.log(operation.response.responseText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding what limit is for.  Limit is sent as a param to books.json so that if that was a dynamic content page (like .jsp or .php) you could use limit when you are generating the rows to actually know how many you want to show up in the responsetext.  Without any functionality on your .json page, the limit configuration is meaningless.

Comment: If you feel that it is correct, hit the green checkmark next to it too :)